# Is it possible to make Windows treat my USB stick as a portable device to skirt Removable Media Protection?

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, security-warning

I am trying to move a file I downloaded on my work computer to my laptop via a thumb drive but I keep getting an access denied error because my company uses Symantec and has set a block on on removable media.

However, there seems to be a really bad loophole in Symantec’s software that treats my phone as a “Portable Media Player” and will allow me to move files as long as it’s a “Portable Device.”

Knowing that, can I do something that will load a thumb drive as a “Portable Device” instead of as a mapped drive? Either way I can get my file across, just wondering for wondering’s sake. Also it’s annoying unplugging my phone. I’d rather just use a thumb drive.

Comment: You're better off asking IT for help then risking your job via a workaround. You might point out the loophole to them.

Comment: Why is my comment being edited? Also, I work in IT. That's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Instead of asking for a software ask a generic question.